# Use PuTTY's -m parameter to run script on login

Tags: putty

In the [putty manual outlines how to use the program with command line parameters](https://the.earth.li/%7Esgtatham/putty/0.74/htmldoc/Chapter3.html#using-cmdline). I have this setup with a shortcut on my toolbar to automatically log me into my server.

```
"C:\Program Files\PuTTY\putty.exe" username@server -pw .... -C
```

However, I'd like to run a simple script to automatically put me in a specific directory once I log in. I saw there's the -m command to give "a local file name, and it will read a command from that file".

With a file at the destination I've tried the following options:

```
"C:\Program Files\PuTTY\putty.exe" username@server -pw .... -C -m "C:\local file\script.txt"

"C:\Program Files\PuTTY\putty.exe" username@server -pw .... -C -m "C:\local file\script.sh"

"C:\Program Files\PuTTY\putty.exe" username@server -pw .... -C -m "/server/file/with/755/permissions/script.sh"
```

And nothing worked.

I'm trying to find an example of this parameter and use but I can't find one. How can I properly use this parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting the [docs](https://the.earth.li/%7Esgtatham/putty/0.74/htmldoc/Chapter3.html#S3.8.3.6),

> The -m option performs a similar function to the ‘Remote command’ box in the SSH panel of the PuTTY configuration box (see [section 4.19.1](https://the.earth.li/%7Esgtatham/putty/0.74/htmldoc/Chapter4.html#config-command)). However, the -m option expects to be given a local file name, and it will read a command from that file.

And quoting section 4.19.1,

> In SSH, you don't have to run a general shell session on the server. Instead, you can choose to run a single specific command (such as a mail user agent, for example). If you want to do this, enter the command in the ‘Remote command’ box.
>
> Note that most servers will close the session after executing the command.

Note the "instead". This is not a command to run *in* the shell before passing control to you. This is a command to run **instead of a shell**.

You can't just put `cd /wherever` and expect to end up in a shell in directory `/wherever`. You might be able to write a command that will run a shell in the directory you want and give you control, though I'm not sure how to get all the details correct.

Comment: Thank you very much. I see now that it will not work for my purposes, but in the future if I wanted to run a command and have it close instead of giving me a shell, how would I format the parameter? I would have expected at least one of my attempts above would have run my script before closing, but none of them did that.

Comment: @GFL: Your first attempt looks fine to me, though you're not supposed to have a whole script - only a single command is officially supported.